# How to know which label was selected?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

There will be a few label in my div. The user can choose to edit the label or change font after clicking on the label.

If the user want to change font size, the user click the label then select the font size in the dropdown list.

My problem is how to know which label is selected/highlighted in order to change font size?

E.g. Of change the size of one label

jQuery

```
$("#size").on('change',function(){
   var getValue=$(this).val();
   $("#label1").css("font-size",this.value + "px");

});
```

HTML

```
<select name="fontsize" id="size">
    <option value="6">6</option>
    <option value="8">8</option>
    <option value="9">9</option>
</select>

<label class="pull-left" id="label1" >New Text</label>
<label class="pull-left" id="label2" >New Text</label>
<label class="pull-left" id="label3" >New Text</label>
```

Comment: Show us your current and relevant code or what you have tried so far.

Comment: Here you go. This is the example of changing one of the label size

Comment: Please, show us your HTML code to properly help you

Comment: @luigonsec Please take a look

Comment: I hope my answer helps you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### HTML CODE

```
<!-- All the labels could be clicked-->
<label class="clickableLabel">Label1</label>
<label class="clickableLabel">Label2</label>
<label class="clickableLabel">Label2</label>
```

### JQUERY CODE

```
// When clicking in a label, a new class is added
$(".clickableLabel").on("click",function(){

     // Comment this line to allow multiple selection
     $(".selected").removeClass("selected");
     $(this).toggleClass("selected");

});

// When the select changes, the font size of the label changes too
$("#size").on("change",function(){

     var getValue=$(this).val();
     $(".selected").css("font-size", getValue + "px");

})
```

Comment: I have written my own classes, but you can use you own without problem

Comment: Perfect! Thank you so much! You help me a lot!